# Edit_Post hook seems to fire twice

Tags: wordpress

I found something similar here: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/publish_post-hook-multiple-firing

Basically I am using the edit hook in wordpress to add some data to a table, and the function gets called twice. The first time it goes with its default values, the second time it has the actual data.

Anyone come up with this issue? Is it really an issue or I am missing something?

Action:

```
add_action('edit_post', 'my_func');
```

Function:

```
function my_func() {
    if(!wp_is_post_revision($post_ID)) {

    // Code to get $_POST data, omitted

    // Call to the database here, omitted
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`edit_post` is triggered when you edit **AND** update the post(even when a comment is added to that post) . What you need is the `publish_post` hook. Read [this page](http://adambrown.info/p/wp_hooks/hook/%7B%24new_status%7D_%7B%24post-%3Epost_type%7D) for more info.

Comment: Gotcha I will test ASAP and when I do will accept answer (positive it will though!)

Comment: This didn't seem to work. The event is still getting fired up more than once.

Comment: Aha! It gets fired up several times. I just determined the trigger is called also when I click on "Add Post"...

Comment: Ah. save_post is called everytime the form is saved. I believe the plugin I am looking for is publish_post. http://wordpress.org/support/topic/save_post-called-repeatedly Edit your answer so I can credit you accordingly please.

Comment: Updated my answer. No Codex page for this hook for now.

Comment: It's a wiki, if you think something is missing, you can add it yourself.